# Moving a folder with "sudo mv", how to preserve ACLs?

Tags: command-line, permission, file-transfer, acl

I'm moving a whole folder from one volume to another (both HFS+), using `sudo mv`, and thought ACLs would be preserved. However at the end of transfer I see that they haven't been kept, and since mv deleted the files in the original volume I can't restore them.

Why did this happen, and how to do it right next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use the `ditto` command since it is aware of resource forks, HFS attributes as well as ACL. You can alias it or try and rewire  your brain to use ditto as best fits your workflow.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` uses `cp` when moving files between different volumes, and it looks like the [`-p` option](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) isn't used, so ACL aren't preserved.

However if moved in the same volume ACLs are of course preserved.

Comment: In macOS 12, the man page for `mv` mentions that `mv` uses `rm -f destination_path && cp -pRP source_file destination && rm -rf source_file` to accomplish a cross-file system/cross-volume move. Note that the `-p` option for `cp` is mentioned in this snippet.